# jquery mobile user interface vectors or something very similar?

Tags: vector, icon, mobile, interface-design

Does anyone know where to get jquery mobile vector .ai files preferrable?
In need to do some mockups in high quality for print but cannot find any ilustrator or vector psd templats for this.

Is there something that looks very similar to the UI on
http://jquerymobile.com ?

Comment: I assume you're referring to jQuery UI. Most everything in jQuery UI is going to be resolution independent as it's all CSS. One option might be to load your page in your browser, zoom in, screen shot, and then use that for print.

Answer (score 3):

On http://jquerymobile.com/resources/ there is a listing [including a link to the icon author's website](http://andymatthews.net/read/2012/02/28/jQuery-Mobile-Icon-Pack-Extra-icons-for-your-jQuery-Mobile-project!) and the actual files can be found as a [zip download on github](https://github.com/commadelimited/jQuery-Mobile-Icon-Pack). Even though there is a `.eps` file in the `assets` folder, the icons in the `.psd` file seem rasterized.

Maybe [contacting the author](http://andymatthews.net/contact/) directly would be a possiblity, if you really need the vector files (given, there are such - many icon designers work on pixel level).

Answer (score 0):

An excellent resource is http://365psd.com/

As the URL name suggests, they post 1 psd every day of the year, resulting in a large collection of free Photoshop files, most of which are rather nice looking web UI elements. They are obviously PSD files, not AI, but in most cases the elements are created using shapes and vector masks to make them scalable.